# get Woocommerce product format json for WP_Query

Tags: php, plugin-development, hooks, rest-api

I'm building custom endpoint REST API and I need the same format wooCommerce gave for its post type ( product ), using the `WP_Query()` class.

I tried the `wc_Product_Query` and for some reason not working with my `tax_query`, So instead, I start using the Wordpress query `WP_Query` and works very well but the wooCommerce has much data than just default post like price, categories, images ...etc

So How I implement those data on my query?

**My code**:

```php
function hash_realated_products() {

    $query = new WP_Query( array(

                                 'post_type'=> 'product',
                                 'per_page' => 10,
                                 'status' => 'publish',
                                 'orderby' => 'rand',
                                 'tax_query' => array(
                                                      'relation' => 'AND',
                                                      array(
                                                            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
                                                            'field'    => 'name',
                                                            'terms'    => array('component'),
                                                            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
                                                            'compare' => 'LIKE'
                                                            ),
                                                      array(
                                                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                                            'field'    => 'term_id',
                                                            'terms'     =>  array(17), // When you have more term_id's seperate them by komma.
                                                            'operator'  => 'IN'
                                                        )
                                                      )
                                         ));
    $products = $query->get_posts();

    wp_reset_postdata();

    return $products;

}
```

Comment: You don't need to call `wp_reset_postdata` as you haven't called `the_post` or `set_postdata`, and your `NOT IN` parameters make this an **extremely** slow query to run, as does the `rand` order. You could speed this up significantly by adding an extra category named `not-component`. Both the `rand` order, and the `NOT IN` will make `mysql` do a full table copy, first ot create a new temporary table in memory but with the order randomised, and again to elminate the `NOT IN`, then it will finally perform the query

Comment: My client has 1000 product and some of them has a specific tag called `component` that we need to exclude it from the response of the above query, So it there any better solution ?

Comment: Like I said, add a tag to the other products that represents the inverse, e.g. `not-component`, then query for those

Comment: K. I get it, you just wanna remove the component tag product from that category I call to make the query faster ( to let me not using the NOT IN operator )

is there a code to do this once instead of doing manually from the panel